# Is it possible to return a read-only ObservableCollection that the caller can't modify?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, observablecollection, readonly

Consider the following code:

```
public ObservableCollection<Message> Messages {
   get { return new ObservableCollection<Message>(); }
}
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent the caller code from adding/removing/changing items?

EDIT: Sorry, everyone, I just noticed it's a [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763696/how-can-i-make-a-read-only-observablecollection-property), but the accepted answer is wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I make a read-only ObservableCollection property?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763696/how-can-i-make-a-read-only-observablecollection-property)

Comment: The accepted answer on the original question is now correct and better formulated than the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about using [ReadOnlyObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653203.aspx)

Code would be:

```
public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message> Messages 
{
  get { return new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message>(new ObservableCollection<Message>()); }
}
```

Having read about[ReadOnlyObservableCollection Anti Pattern](http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/03/readonlyobservablecollection_anti-pattern.html) I realise the above is the not a good approach and may lead to subtle bugs.  The suggested approach is:

```
public class MyClass
{
  public MyClass()
  {
    myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Message>();
    myReadOnlyCollection = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message>(myCollection);
  }

  public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message> Messages 
  {
    get { return myReadOnlycollection; }
  }

  private readonly ObservableCollection<Message> myCollection;
  private readonly ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message> myReadOnlyCollection;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need a read only ObservableCollection.
If this collection is read only you don't need to observe it.
Consider a Collection<T>

Comment: I'm thinking he *wants* to be able to modify it, but he doesn't want to let others do so.  He *does* want them to be notified of changes that he made, however.

Comment: It is quite common to want to expose a *read-only view* for a collection and have the changes be observable to the outside. Often you want to make changes in response to events, but want to do it in a controlled fashion inside the class, not at the whim of outside code.

Answer (score 2):

Return a `ReadOnlyObservableCollection` instead:

```
private ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message> _Messages;

public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Message> Messages {
   get { this._Messages = this._Messages ?? new ReadOnlyObservableCollection(new ObservableCollection<Message>()); return this._Messages; }
}
```

Comment: Antipattern, see: http://code.logos.com/blog/2009/03/readonlyobservablecollection_anti-pattern.html

Comment: Fixed this four year old issue.

Answer (score 1):

What about to use the [ReadOnlyObservableCollection< T >](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653203.aspx)