# Keep the collections in the list in MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, microsoft-metro, prism

currently im having troubles in keeping the collections in the list in the mvvm, every time that i navigate away and return to a page, the list keeps getting empty. how am i going to deal with this? can someone help me with this?
The Model:
I have not implemented the others yet because i cant add items to the list

```
 class CartData
        {
            public int Cakeprice { get; set; }
            public ImageSource ImagePath { get; set; }
            public string Caketype { get; set; }
            public string Cakename { get; set; }
            public int TotalItems { get; set; }

        }
```

The View Model:

```
class CartingDataSource : BindableBase
    {
public ObservableCollection<CartData> _cartData;

public ObservableCollection<CartData> CartData
        {

         get {
             return _cartData;
             }
        set {

                SetProperty(ref _cartData, value);
           }
        }
 private DelegateCommand _addItemCommand;
        public ICommand AddItemCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_addItemCommand == null)
                {
                    _addItemCommand = new DelegateCommand(AddToCart);
                }
                return _addItemCommand;
            }
        }

 public void AddToCart() {

            CartData.Add(new CartData { Cakename = "Black Forest", Cakeprice = 104 });
                   }
```

}
The View:

```
.....

 <Page.DataContext>
        <vm:CartingDataSource/>
    </Page.DataContext>
   ....
<ListView
            x:Name="itemListView"
            AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsListView"
            AutomationProperties.Name="Items"
            TabIndex="1"
            Margin="-10,130,0,264"
            Padding="120,0,0,60"

            ItemsSource="{Binding cartData}"
            IsSwipeEnabled="False" Grid.RowSpan="2" ItemClick="itemListView_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="itemListView_SelectionChanged_1" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="6">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Width="60" Height="60">
                            <Image Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}" Source="Assets/TempPic.jpg"/>
                        </Border>
                        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,0,0,0">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cakename}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" MaxHeight="40"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cakeprice}" Style="{StaticResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}" TextWrapping="NoWrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,10"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: are you re-instantiating the collection somewhere in code ?

Comment: @cvraman no im not reinstantiating my code. here is the full code in my my previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163110/maintaining-the-collection-in-a-list-observablecollection

Comment: Which Container are you using on your Prism solution? Is it MEF or Unity? If Unity is the case, you should notice that the container does not mantain a reference to the View and it resolves new instances each time you would navigate to it. Therefore, when you would navigate away from the View, that instance would get disposed, getting a new View/ViewModel instance with an empty collection each time you would navigate back to the specified View. For more information, see the MSDN Prism [chapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921140(v=pandp.40).aspx) of Managing Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

When are you creating an instance of the collection?

I suggest you make the collection readonly and create an instance only when needed, of the backing store field.

```
public ObservableCollection<CartData> CartData
        {

         get {
                if( _cartData == null ) _cartData = new ObservableCollection<CartData> ();
                return _cartData;
             }
        set {

                SetProperty(ref _cartData, value);
           }
        }
```

Comment: but this give me an error : "Readonly is not valid to this item"

Comment: Doesn't really matter.

Comment: but this give me an error : "Readonly is not valid to this item"

Comment: Try using the ReadOnlyObservableCollection .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346948/is-it-possible-to-return-a-read-only-observablecollection-that-the-caller-cant

The basic idea is to create a single instance of the Collection for the Application's lifetime.

Comment: oh btw if im going to delete a certain item how is going to be?

Comment: CartData.Remove(cartItem);

Comment: @bit: don't do read/write properties like this. Consider this code: `obj.CardData = null; Debug.Assert(obj.CardData == null)`. Assert will fail, because getter ignores, that someone set this property to `null` from outside. Besides, your answer doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: If you could tell me when are you instantiating the collection I could give you a precise answer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22163110/maintaining-the-collection-in-a-list-observablecollection here is my previous question about that

Comment: @Dennis, yep.. hack.luminence , can you post all the details in this question itself?

Comment: there that's it. that's the method on how am i going get the list that  is being added. the other page for adding items is this code in the answer you can also chat me regarding to this. thanks!

Comment: it seems to be no one can answer me again :(

Answer (score 0):

Form the information you have provided I can understand that you are not instantiating the ObservableCollection CartData but, it looks like some where CartData is getting set to null.

With limited information about question I wold suggest you to use PRISM's one of the best feature EventAggregator. It will solve your problem.

EventAggregator is something which will help you to Publish the your Model(CartData) with values and Subscribe it as and when you need it.

Some helpful Links

[Trying to understand the event aggregator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436853/trying-to-understand-the-event-aggregator-pattern)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122.aspx