# Is there IObservableCollection interface or some kind of that?

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I want my interfaces to have property

```
IReadOnlyCollection<SomeType> Items { get; }
```

I also want this collection to be observable

```
INotifyCollectionChanged Items { get; }
```

But there is no way to declare duplicate properties.

I **REALLY** searched MSDN, googling for something like *ReadOnlyObservableCollection* or maybe *IObservableCollection* and didn't find anything. I really need this type of interface, so I will probably just introduce my own. But I don't want to invent a wheel here.

**Question:** I am right that there are no default C# interface that combines *INotifyCollectionChanged* and *IEnumerable*?

**p.s.** I know that there is ReadOnlyObservableCollection class out there, but one crucial detail here - it's not covariant like IReadOnlyCollection. And I do want this covariance

Comment: Returning a INotifyCollectionChanged does not mean the thing will be observable. Whatever implements IReadOnlyCollection has to also implement INotifyCollectionChanged. What you are doing there does does not make any sense for me.

Comment: Help me to write it correctly. I want to have one interface for property that will represent IReadOnlyCollection (or IEnumerable) and also fire notifications like INotifyCollectionChanged. This makes sense?

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763696/how-can-i-make-a-read-only-observablecollection-property) -- in particular the answer from @MeirionHughes where he starts with __"I don't like using ReadOnlyObservableCollection<T> as it seems like a mistake / broken class"__ and then offers up a simple alternative in about 20 lines of code.  I think he has provided what you may be looking for -- including covariance.

Comment: The same class can implement more than one interface.

Comment: @DavidTansey YES, that's exactly what I want. And also it really looks like I will create those interfaces myself. My hope was that I missed something like that in some Microsoft namespaces. Because it seemed like a pretty useful contract to have in default libraries.